# How can I use regular expression to select the columns of data frame in r?

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, select

I have the following data frame.

```
D <- data.frame(A123.case.vs.B123.Cntl._FC = 1:4, B123.case.vs.B123.Cntl._FC = 0:3, A123.case.vs.D123.Cntl._FC= 2:5, FC = 1:4, A123.case= 0:3, B123.cntrl = 0:3)
```

I would like to select the first 3 columns using regular expression.

here is what I am trying but it does not work.

```
D %>% select(contains("case.vs.[a-z]*[0-9].cntl"))
```

Do you have any idea where is my problem?

Thanks

Comment: `grep("case.vs.[a-z]*[0-9].cntl", names(D))` returns 0. So it looks like the problem is your regex pattern

Comment: The problem is if you check `?select_helpers` `contains - Contains a literal string.`  Here, you have included both literal and regex which won't work as it would be looking for the `[a-z]*`as literal pattern

Answer (score 4):

The following regular expression does what the question asks for.

```
library(dplyr)

D %>% select(matches('case\\.vs\\.[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]+'))
#  A123.case.vs.B123.Cntl._FC B123.case.vs.B123.Cntl._FC A123.case.vs.D123.Cntl._FC
#1                          1                          0                          2
#2                          2                          1                          3
#3                          3                          2                          4
#4                          4                          3                          5
```

Comment: thanks. I would like to add "cntl" to my expression as well. I am using this command    matches("case\\.vs\\.[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]].cntl\\+")   But it is not working.

Comment: Try 'case\\.vs\\.[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]+\\.Cntl'. The '+' means one or more of the preceding term i.e one or more digits in this case.  You also need to use '\\' in front of the '.' so that it is treated literally,